# turning tree data into json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save my data in a tree structure into json but I am having a difficult time doing it.
My tree node has a name and a list of children.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.children = dict()
```

I am running BFS to try to capture the structure but without success. the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to add children after the first iteration since all the dictionary key will be the same "name" and "children"

```
queue.put(root)
data = {}
while not queue.empty():
    node = queue.get()
    children = []
    data.update({"name": node.name, "children": children})
    for child in node.children:
        children.append({"name": node.children[child].name, "children": []})
        queue.put(node.children[child])

with open("test.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

With the current code I am unable to add item to the result dict because I am using the same keys for every iteration. The second iteration will erase the entries from the first iteration. Also, I don't know how to reference a specific dict in the children list in subsequent iterations.

this is the current result.json. only the last entry in the last iteration got saved

```
{
    "name": "ffff",
    "children": []
}
```

I don't know if running BFS is the only way to do this. Maybe there are other better and easier ways to do it?

For example, I want to achieve this desired result below at the end. The real tree is significantly larger than this however.

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "aaaa",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "bbbb",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "cccc"
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
        },
        {
            "name": "dddd",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "eeee",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "ffff"
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
        }
}
```

I also tried directly do

```
json_file = json.dumps(root, indent=2)
```

but it gave me an error

```
TypeError: Object of type Node is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: What do you get instead? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't derive from your code what the values of the keys are in the `children` dictionary, but I guess they are the names of those children.

You can do this with BFS, but it is easier with DFS. Your code never moves down the structure (via `children`) that you create in `data`, so it is expected that you don't get a nested output.

But, anyway, here is a DFS solution:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.children = dict()

    # A method to easily add a child to this node:
    def add(self, child):
        self.children[child.name] = child
        return self

    # A method to return the current tree as a nested dictionary
    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "name": self.name,
            "children": [child.to_dict() for child in self.children.values()]
        }

# Example: create the tree from the question
root = Node("root").add(
    Node("aaaa").add(
        Node("bbbb").add(
            Node("cccc")
        )
    )
).add(
    Node("dddd").add(
        Node("eeee").add(
            Node("ffff")
        )
    )
)

# Produce the JSON output
import json
print(json.dumps(root.to_dict(), indent=2))
```

Comment: Thanks! however, your solution would get me the example json above. My real tree is significantly larger with thousands of nodes. can you give me a more general solution with DFS? Thanks!

Comment: The number of nodes is not relevant for this, but the property structure of a Node instance is. This is quite generic, except for the Node class and the properties ("name", "children"). Did you run it with your data?

Answer (score 0):

#### Flat queue BFS solution

The problem is that on each iteration you are updating the same top-level keys of `data`, even for nested nodes. To fix your current approach with the queue, we also need to keep track of the point of the resulting `data` dict at which to insert the transformed node:

```py
data = {}

# keep track of current node AND current sub-dict of data
queue.put((root, data))

while not queue.empty():
    node, subdata = queue.popleft()

    children = []

    for _key, child in node.children.items():
        # create an empty sub-dict which will be populated on next iteration
        child_data = {}
        children.append(child_data)
        queue.append((child, child_data))

    subdata.update({"name": node.name, "children": children})
```

Some notes:

- When iterating over dict, it's usually preferrable to do it like so:

  ```
  for key, value in data.items():
      ...
  ```

  This saves you from fetching the value with `value = data[key]` inside the loop and is plain cleaner.
- I've noticed you use `queue.Queue` for a queue - but that is a special thread-safe queue used mostly in multithreading context. For a simple case such as this you are better off with [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).
- The whole thing works as expeceted because of how Python passes object references around. E.g. `children.append(child_data)` only stores a reference to a dict, so when updating it on subsequent iteration we can be sure it's the same dict in the same place in the whole tree, not just an isolated copy.

#### Recursive solution

This can be solved much cleaner with recursion:

```py
def format_tree(node):
    children = []
    
    for _key, child in node.children.items():
        formatted_child = format_tree(child)
        children.append(formatted_child)

    return {"name": node.name, "children": children}

format_tree(root)
```

There is no remembering sub-dicts and their respective locations, no updating in-place, and it's much easier to comprehend. The only potential downside is that for *extremely* deeply nested trees you may get a stack overflow.

#### Dumping as json

Lastly, if you want to be able to do `json_file = json.dumps(root, indent=2)` directly on your tree structure, have a look at implementing a custom [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) for your type.